# How to acquire video feed in python using a wireless webcam setup on my android device?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, webcam, video-capture

Alright, so my basic aim is to do some video processing. But I want to do so in real time using the feed from a camera. I've downloaded this app on my android phone called [IP webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en). Using this app I can create a wireless camera feed, which I'm able to access using the link http://192.168.1.2:8080/video

If I insert the above link in my browser I'm able to retrieve the video feed, however I'm not able to do so using python. I tried doing something along the lines of `cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.2:8080/video')`, but I wasn't able to retrieve the video feed.

I'm using python v2.7.12, numPy and openCV v2.4.13

It would be really helpful if you could tell me why my current method is failing and what I'm supposed to do, or give me an alternative approach to the problem (keeping in mind I want to use my android device as a wireless webcam and acquire the video feed in python).

Answer (score 0):

Without an error code, or some other debugging information, there is too little information to give a definitive answer, but here is something that worked for me when I had a similar problem.

I am using an AXIS IP webcam and to view the stream, I go to `http://192.168.206.241/view/viewer_index.shtml?id=392`. However this includes the video stream embedded in a viewer. Using this URL confuses the `VideoCapture()` object. Instead, I had to drag the embedded stream into a new tab, which gave me a new URL, `http://192.168.206.241/mjpg/video.mjpg`. Using this as the string for the `VideoCapture()` parameter, I have success.

Just looking at the URL you use, it doesn't seem to have an extension. This might be the problem.